# How do I delete a user from the master database when the user has been deleted from the Server Logins using the SSMS Object Explorer

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am using an Azure SQL Database. I deleted some users from a Azure SQL database after I saw them mentioned in a Vulnerability Assessment report. Here's how I deleted them:

1. Log in to SSMS
2. Expand the Object Explorer tree
3. Expand the 'Security' folder
4. Expand the 'Logins' folder
5. Highlight the user
6. Right-click and select 'Delete'

I went back to the Vulnerability Assessment blade and ran a new 'Scan' but the users I deleted still show up in the list. The list included SQL code to show that my users still exist. I ran that code back in SSMS in the master database and confirmed my users still exist. Here's the relevant code:

`SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals`

When I run the following code, I get an error saying the user does not exist ('or you do not have permission' - but I am a server admin so I ruled that out):

`DROP LOGIN <username>`

**Note:** I already deleted the users from all databases on the server.

How do I get rid of these logins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two concepts with security at play here, and in general how SQL Server works. There are [**Logins**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-login?view=sql-server-ver15) and [**Users**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-user?view=sql-server-ver15), which the differences are discussed a little further in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1134357/5059085). You've deleted the **Logins** which is server level, but the **Users** associated to those **Logins** still exist at the database level, which has its own **Security** node you can expand and then a **Users** node below it.

Whenever you map a **Login** to a database (to grant database permissions) it creates a **User** in that database.

Example:

[image: Delete Users from Database]

Comment: oh yeah, I forgot to mention that I had already deleted the users from all databases on the server. But I must say your image makes this an excellent answer to that issue.

Comment: Also, your image shows an on-prem version. I am using an Azure SQL Database (where there is no 'Properties' context menu option).

Comment: @Sartoris are you certain the user is deleted from all databases? If you're seeing the **User** in the `sys.database_principals` system view then likely that **User** still exists, and specifically in the `master` database if that's the context where that system view is showing that **User** record. I'd recommend double checking the **Security --> Users** node in the `master` database. Especially since **SSMS** is using the same *source of truth* as `sys.database_principals`. So that would be very weird otherwise.

Comment: yes, @David Browne pointed out the user is in the master database as well. Since you added this comment before he replied, I accept your answer.

Comment: @satoris Great, glad you were able to figure it out! Yup, just to reiterate that when you query `sys.database_principals` it's only referring to the database context you're currently running it under. In your case, this was the `master` database.

Answer (score 1):

SSMS should display this warning when you delete the login:

> Deleting server logins does not delete the database users associated
> with the logins. To complete the process, delete the users in each
> database. It may be necessary to first transfer the ownership of
> schemas to new users.

And so in the master database don't run

```
DROP LOGIN <username>
```

.  The login has already been dropped.  Instead run

```
DROP USER <username>
```

Comment: You're saying that the the message above refers to the master database as well. That's the part I wasn't getting! Thanks.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Hey David, I've always wondered why it doesn't automatically remove the **Users** too or at least offer the option to do so, when you delete a **Login** via **SSMS**, any thoughts why?...just a legacy design that never needed to be upgraded? (I would assume the more common use case is the end user would want to delete all **Users** associated to that **Login** too, but maybe not?)

Comment: @J.D. - I wondered that too, until I actually had to delete an admin type user who had a bunch of roles and permissions that were associated to that user (grantor vs grantee). It appears MS decided that the decision to reassign those objects to another user should be left to the admin (although Microsoft could default the 'orphaned grantors' to dbo). The code to add this feature would not be trivial. I'm sure this was a debate amongst SSMS engineers years ago!

Comment: Database users can own objects and grant permissions, and there can be an arbitrary number of databases.  So cascading a DROP LOGIN to all the mapped users would be tricky.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thanks! I would've thought it would be rather simple, especially since **SSMS** already knows the **User Mapping** result set, whether it was accomplished iteratively via application code, or dynamically with `sp_MSforeachdb` or **Dynamic SQL**. But I guess it does make sense for the developer to take a second thought concerning the owned objects of a **user** before automatically dropping it. I guess also there are contexts where developers would want **users** to impersonate (with `EXECUTE AS`) for permissions reasons but without them being able to login to the server.

Comment: Yep.  A user WITHOUT LOGIN is a useful thing.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - some of the answers here are for IaaS/on-prem Sql security that don't apply 100% to Azure Sql.  Azure is NOT the same thing especially when it comes to security.  Remember there is ONLY 1 database in Azure Sql.  And the GUI in SSMS is very limited and buggy on Azure Sql.  And then there's AAD security instead of windows AD....lots different there like using MIs.

One example.....In Azure Sql, you don't need a login as the master level but then you must specify a default db/catalog when you connect.  For master db, can create a login, and/or a user or none! You can just grant user at the user DB level (not master db).  Welcome to Azure Sql.

That's just one of many oddities about azure sql.  Again people - if you haven't used Azure sql db don't assume you know what's going on as it's a whole new world.

Here are useful scripts for showing security in azure sql since the SSMS GUI is very limited.  Note that it shows different security when you're pointing at master than when you point at user db (note "use dbname" doesn't work in azure sql).

-- Show user/groups/db roles names and access
SELECT DISTINCT pr.principal_id, pr.name, pr.type_desc,
pr.authentication_type_desc, pe.state_desc, pe.permission_name
FROM sys.database_principals AS pr
JOIN sys.database_permissions AS pe
ON pe.grantee_principal_id = pr.principal_id
--where pr.name IN ('SalesforceTest')
ORDER BY pr.name

-- show role membership
SELECT DP1.name AS DatabaseRoleName,
isnull (DP2.name, 'No members') AS DatabaseUserName
FROM sys.database_role_members AS DRM
RIGHT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals AS DP1
ON DRM.role_principal_id = DP1.principal_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals AS DP2
ON DRM.member_principal_id = DP2.principal_id
WHERE DP1.type = 'R'
ORDER BY DP1.name;